# How to have npm install a typescript dependency from a GitHub url?

Tags: typescript, github, npm, npm-install

Consider the following scenario:

- There is a code library.  The library is written in TypeScript and the typescript code is published in GitHub.  The `package.json` file has a build script which creates JavaScript files based on the TypeScript code and a publish script which then places the resulting JS files on npm.
- I make a fork of the GitHub repo, make some modifications to the typescript files and push those changes to GitHub.  (I also open a PR to the original GitHub repo but there is a time lage before these changes can be merged.)
- I wish to consume these code changes in a downstream NPM package so in the downstream packages I change the reference (in the downstream's `package.json` file) to the modified package to the GitHub URL of my fork and do an `npm install`.

This doesn't work because:

- The package.json file of the modified package does not list the typescript files in the `dist` field, only the automatically generated JS files so the TypeScript files are not pulled during the npm install.
- The compiled JS files aren't present since they aren't checked in to GitHub.

How can I solve this? Is there a way that I can modify the behavoir of `npm install` so that it fetches files in the repo that aren't in `dist` and then runs the build script during the install?

Comment: I can only think of maintaining a separate `build` branch (a branch with same name as a folder would sometimes confuses Git, so avoid `dist`).

Answer (score 28):

I had the same problem. Saw a lot of articles about monorepos (links below), but not much about how to split a TypeScript project into separate repositories.

In short, you need to build JS files at one step or the other.

See https://github.com/stared/yarn-adding-pure-typescript-package-example for a working code example.

So, there are a few solutions. Let's say that the repository is `someuser/package-to-import`

### Postinstall

Using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) you can get the project directly from a GitHub repository:

```
yarn add someuser/package-to-import#master
```

(or the same with `npm install someuser/package-to-import#master`)

If you work on a fork of this repository, you can make your life easier by adding to `package.json` in `package-to-import` repo this part:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "postinstall": "tsc --outDir ./build"
  }
```

Now it just works with `yarn add/upgrade` with no extra scripts.
Alternatively, you can do it semi-manually, i.e. create a script in your main repository `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    ...,
    "upgrade-package-to-import": "yarn upgrade package-to-import && cd node_modules/package-to-import && yarn build"
  }
```

### Link

There is a different approach to clone the repository into a different folder, build the files, and link it.

```
git clone git@github.com:someuser/package-to-import.git
cd package-to-import
npm run build  # or any other instruction to build
npm link
```

If you use yarn, the two last lines would be:

```
yarn build
yarn link
```

Then, enter the folder of your project and write

```
npm link package-to-import
```

or in case of yarn

```
yarn link package-to-import
```

These are symlinks, so when you pull from the repo and build files, you will use the updated version.

See also:

- [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html) and[yarn link](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/) official documentations
- [The magic behind npm link](https://medium.com/@alexishevia/the-magic-behind-npm-link-d94dcb3a81af)

### Monorepos

An entirely different approach.
With mixed advice for using git submodules:

- [4 Ways to Go Monorepo in 2019](https://hackernoon.com/4-ways-to-go-monorepo-in-2019-ea5d19fc1f08)
- [4 Git Submodules Alternatives You Should Know](https://codeburst.io/4-git-submodules-alternatives-you-should-know-592095859b0)
- [A (multi-) monorepo setup with Git Submodules](https://www.jannikbuschke.de/blog/git-submodules/)

Comment: So my postinstall in the module is `"postinstall": "tsc -d -p ."`. If I now run `npx tsc` in my project that uses the module, it tries to compile the ts files in the module.

Comment: I think it tries to import the `.ts` files instead of the defition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346535/typescript-imports-source-instead-of-output made a post in case someone cares

Answer (score 13):

The [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) for the `prepack` script suggest that it is run after a dependency is installed from a git repo. Try putting something like this in the `package.json` of the git dependency:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "call the build script"
  }
}
```

This should build the package after you `npm install` it, which sounds like what you want to do. I'm not sure if there are any other problems you are having beyond that.

Comment: Looks like `prepare` also works. -- https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: Recently, I've found that `prepack` hasn't been working for me, despite what the documentation says, but that `prepare` works well. However, this seems to have gathered 13 upvotes, so I'm reluctant to change my answer which seems to have helped many people. Is this working for people? Or are people, like me, finding this doesn't work and using @Polv's `prepare` instead?

Answer (score 4):

#### Build the files in your fork and commit those to your fork's repo/branch.

I was running into the exact same issue that you were. Amazing that I was able to Google my way onto your StackOverflow question, really, because it's a difficult issue to describe.

In short, I had to fork the `react-native-webview` library in order to update the `kotlinVersion` in order to support Gradle Plugin 6.0.0.

I forked it just fine and bumped that version just fine, as you can see [here](https://github.com/cntral/react-native-webview/commit/ab9745cee17baf602592880aeed30e9319be5b93).

I then added this specific fork and branch to my `package.json` file:

```json
"react-native-webview": "github:cntral/react-native-webview#5_8_2"
```

I would do `npm install` after this and would get `error Command "tsc" not found.`

After much digging, there's a `"prepack": "yarn build"` script in this library's `package.json` that will try to run whenever it is included as a git dependency like this. But we're not using TypeScript so it tries to run `yarn build` which runs `yarn tsc` and `tsc` can't be found.

Okay, so I tried to add `typescript` as a `devDependency` to my `package.json` to see if that would fix it. It didn't. I tried using `yarn install` instead of `npm install` to see if that would fix it. It would install it just fine but if you looked at the `node_modules/react-native-webview` directory, the converted JavaScript files that were supposed to be in `lib/` weren't there. So that didn't work.

Then I thought, if all this is doing is trying to transpile the TypeScript files into normal JavaScript so it can be consumed by our app, why not do that in our fork and commit those `.js` files. So I did.

I ran `yarn build` in my fork of `react-native-webview`, removed the `lib/` directory from `.gitignore` and then committed those changes, as you can see [here](https://github.com/cntral/react-native-webview/commit/58a66145313f57cbe56598957e7d9519588a7907).

Then I also had to remove the `"prepack": "yarn build"` from the `package.json` of the fork so it wouldn't try to build the library and run `tsc` again, which was done [here](https://github.com/cntral/react-native-webview/commit/f34accf03d429912cc153526ce9ff1e1c0202051).

After that our app was able to consume it just fine, like any other library we consume off of npm or GitHub.

Hope that helps others.

Comment: Problem with this is that if you want to pull request your changes to the source, they probably don't want the built files or the changes you made.

Comment: @meelash Yeah, you're probably right. What's your suggestion then? A postinstall?

Comment: I ended up doing the same to get a fork running. If there's a way to avoid pushing the dist files to my custom fork, I happily take it. Though there isn't any good ressource around where and how one should do it. Apparently, there is a `prepare` step, but I could not get my build command to work from there.

Comment: @k0pernikus That was exactly my experience as well. Decided to move on after a while and get back to real work instead. : )

Comment: I opened a follow-up question, let's see how this goes

https://stackoverflow.com/q/68925785/457268

Comment: @k0pernikus Nice! Keen to see how that turns out for you. I sub'd to that Question but if you get it working, try and remember to post back here. Thanks!