# How to import pure TypeScript package using npm

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I'm building a TypeScript specific package that allows users to automatically consume REST API's and convert the resulting JSON-data into true TypeScript-objects. The package will be used in another TypeScript-project in combination with Vue.js.

I've tried several different ways to compile and repackage the package using Webpack and distribute it through npm. I'm able to compile the package into JavaScript and I generate an index.d.ts which are all correctly configured in the package.json. I am also able to include the package into my other project. When trying to compile my TypeScript/Vue project, I always get a `This dependency was not found` error in the resulting components.

The full error message is:

```
This dependency was not found:

* typescript-rest-mapper in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--12-1!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/sample/SampleDetailsComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&, ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_module
s/ts-loader??ref--12-1!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/sample/SampleOverviewComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& and 7 others
```

This is the package.json and webpack.config.js of the package:

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-rest-mapper",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "description": "Package that allows you to automagically build services that consume REST API's. Received/send data is automatically converted between real TypeScript-objects and JSON-objects.",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack && dts-bundle --configJson dts-bundle.config.json",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/AbyxBelgium/TypeScriptRestMapper.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "service",
    "rest-api",
    "typescript",
    "rest",
    "mapper"
  ],
  "author": "Pieter Verschaffelt",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/AbyxBelgium/TypeScriptRestMapper/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/AbyxBelgium/TypeScriptRestMapper#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "dts-bundle": "^0.7.3",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.3.4000",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "pluralize": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.ts'),
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: [
                    'ts-loader'
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: 'TypeScriptRestMapper',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    mode: 'development'
};
```

In my other project, I include files using for example `import {Service} from "typescript-rest-mapper";`. Note that `Service` is defined in `src/service/Service.ts` in my package. In order to export all the different classes from my package, I've built a index.ts file, which states:

```js
export {Entity} from "./entity/Entity";
export {Service} from "./service/Service";
export {Status} from "./service/Status";
export {Read} from "./decorators/read";
export {ReadArray} from "./decorators/readArray";
export {Store} from "./decorators/store";
export {StoreArray} from "./decorators/storeArray";
export {Update} from "./decorators/update";
export {UpdateArray} from "./decorators/updateArray";
```

I've tried changing the exports to `export * from "./entity/Entity`, etc. What could've gone wrong?

Note: My package is open source and can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/AbyxBelgium/TypeScriptRestMapper

Comment: Your package `main` points to `dist/index.js`  and your webpack cfg looks like it generates `dist/bundle.js` 

Comment: @H.B. Thanks :) I've been checking the configs several times and must have somehow overlooked this everytime. It's working now :)

Comment: Glad that helped. Feel free to *either* delete the question (if you think is probably not helpful for anyone) or post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: See a working example here: https://github.com/stared/yarn-adding-pure-typescript-package-example and my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58257602/907575