# How can I use yarn to add a package from github that uses typescript and has not been compiled?

Tags: git, typescript, npm, ecmascript-6, yarnpkg

I have a git clone of an npm package which i have modified that works perfectly when I use `yarn link <project name>` to add it to a project locally. However, when I push it to GitHub and use `yarn add <repo url>#<branch>` in the same project instead of `yarn link`, I get a compilation error indicating that the typescript/ES6 has not compiled:

```
 SyntaxError Plugin: Unexpected token *
```

Which relates to this line in the package I am adding:

```
import * as path from 'path'
```

How can I get `yarn add` to compile the typescript/ES6 on the fly from the GitHub version just like `yarn link` does with the local version?

I'd rather not build it and commit the result to git as that adds an extra compilation step every time, which I or others might forget.

Also for clarity: I'm not building and pushing to npm as it's a fork of a package that I don't own.

Comment: Have you tried `import * as path from 'path/src'` ?

Comment: @burtek the `path` in question here is the core node `path` module. It ought to work OK.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build files at some point.

Within this repository `yarn build` (or any other build instruction if needed). You need to run it each time after you `yarn upgrade package-you-import`.

For a longer answer, see [my answer to How to have npm install a TypeScript dependency from a GitHub URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58257602/907575).

Answer (score 0):

`yarn add` does not "compile typescript/ES6 on the fly", it just links proper folders. When `yarn add`-ing from github, you can always import from repo's `src` directory:

```js
import * as repo from 'repo/src';
```

Comment: To clarify, the `import *` line is in the package being liked/added, not in the calling code. As I understand it, `yarn link` also just links folders, but that works fine with the local copy. What I need to understand is how/why the `yarn add` from the repo is not working in the same way, despite the folder structure being unchanged.