# Typescript imports module source instead of compilation output

Tags: typescript

I wanted to write a module and just use it for personal projects so I put it up on a private repo on GitHub.

I have a postinstall script on the module that executes: `tsc -d -p .`. Now currently the `.js` and `.d.ts` files right next to the source files. If I import one of my files, for example `import WhatEver from "module/dir/WhatEver"` it seems to use the `.ts` file. This leads to compiler errors as the tsconfigs are not the same.

Now I know I can specify the output directly of `tsc`, but how do I tell typescript that `"module/dir/WhatEver"` should be remapped to `"module/lib/dir/WhatEver" (for example). I was looking around for an option in the package.json, but couldn't find anything that worked.

I have now been searching for a few hours, and there has got to be a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the imports in your consuming application to point to your module's tsconfig's `compilerOptions.outDir` output directory rather than the default directory.

So assuming you have a value of `"dist"` in your `compilerOptions.outDir` your imports would then change from `import { xyz } from '@your/module';` to `import { xyz } from '@your/module/dist';`.