# How to install a npm package from github requiring a build step, e.g. when forking a library?

Tags: javascript, github, npm, yarnpkg, git-fork

Assume you use a library like [`vue3-datepicker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-datepicker). You realize you need to customize something, and as as first step you want to use a custom fork of it.

The issue is, there is a build step when the package is pushed to npm's registry since the project doesn't use plain JavaScript, but may have vue or typescript files.

In this case, that would be `npm run build:component`, though that depends on the project.

Just installing the fork from github via:

```
yarn add <GitHub user name>/<GitHub repository name>#<branch/commit/tag>
```

hence doesn't suffice as then the `./dist` folder doesn't exist.

You'll get really strange errors like:

```
error: [plugin: vite:dep-scan] Failed to resolve entry for package "vue3-datepicker". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: Failed to resolve entry for package "vue3-datepicker". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
```

[As a quick and dirty solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62439106/457268), I removed in my fork the `./dist/` folder from the `.gitignore`, ran the `npm i && npm run build:component` in my fork, and pushed it.

Huge downside is, the `./dist/` folder is now part of that repository, after each change in my fork I also have to build the files again and push those as well.

I rather have the build process triggered in my application *using* my fork. Is there a way from my application to say:

When you install that library, you have to run a certain script once you downloaded all the files?

The solution should be usable for both `npm` and `yarn`, in the sense that the fork my be installed by either one in different applications.

Answer (score 1):

A quote from [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install) Docs

> If the package being installed contains a `prepare` script, its `dependencies` and `devDependencies` will be installed, and the prepare script will be run, before the package is packaged and installed.

so in your fork's `package.json` you can add

```json
"scripts": {
    // ...
    "build:component": "rollup -c build/rollup.config.js",
    "prepare": "yarn build:component || npm run build:component"
}
```

Comment: I dislike it being part of the fork, in case one wants to create a PR from the branch. (It beats comitting the entire dist folder though)

Comment: @k0pernikus, agree, but you can create "installable" brach adding only that script on top of your changes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger builds after installation, you can use the [`postinstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts#npm-install) or a [`build`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-build) script in your `package.json`. In this script, you can create directories and do other setups, using shell commands or javascript programs:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "mkdir dist && npm run build:component",
    "build:component": "some command"
  }
}
```