# Issue with reusable pulumi component in TypeScript (Cannot use import statement outside a module)

Tags: typescript, pulumi

I'm having trouble getting started with reusable components. I'm trying to use TypeScript to author a simple reusable component resource that I can use to deploy an S3 bucket on AWS.

To demonstrate the issue I'm having, I have created two public GitHub repos:

- [`briancaffey/pulumi-alpha`](https://github.com/briancaffey/pulumi-alpha) is the repo that consumes my S3 component
- [`briancaffey/pulumi-beta`](https://github.com/briancaffey/pulumi-beta) is the repo where I define the reusable S3 component

I created both of these with `pulumi new aws-typescript`.

For `pulumi-beta`, I am using the following code to define my component resource:

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws";

export interface S3BucketArgs {
  name: string;
}

export class S3Bucket extends pulumi.ComponentResource {
  public readonly bucket: aws.s3.Bucket;

  constructor(name: string, args: S3BucketArgs, opts?: pulumi.ComponentResourceOptions) {
    super("my:modules:S3Bucket", name, {}, opts);

    this.bucket = new aws.s3.Bucket(name, {
      bucket: args.name,
    }, { parent: this });
  }
}
```

In `pulumi-alpha`, I installed the `pulumi-beta` this package with the following command:

```
npm i git+https://github.com/briancaffey/pulumi-beta.git
```

Then I use it like this in `index.ts`:

```
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import { S3Bucket } from "pulumi-beta";

const bucket = new S3Bucket("my-bucket", {
  name: "my-example-pulumi-bucket",
});

export const bucketName = bucket.bucket.id;
```

Then I ran `tsc` and I can see that it built the application in the `bin` directory:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.bucketName = void 0;
const pulumi_beta_1 = require("pulumi-beta");
const bucket = new pulumi_beta_1.S3Bucket("my-bucket", {
    name: "my-example-pulumi-bucket",
});
exports.bucketName = bucket.bucket.id;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Now I want to run `pulumi preview` to see how things will look, but I get this error:

```
~/git/github/pulumi-alpha$ pulumi preview
Previewing update (dev)

View Live: https://app.pulumi.com/briancaffey/pulumi-alpha/dev/previews/f8469d80-a9d5-4e95-9d9f-8a5830220f5c

     Type                 Name              Plan       Info
 +   pulumi:pulumi:Stack  pulumi-alpha-dev  create     1 error


Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (pulumi-alpha-dev):
    error: Running program '/Users/brian/git/github/pulumi-alpha' failed with an unhandled exception:
    /Users/brian/git/github/pulumi-alpha/node_modules/pulumi-beta/index.ts:1
    import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Back in the `pulumi-beta` repo, I added `"type": "module",` to `package.json`, pushed to GitHub, then reinstalled everything in `pulumi-alpha`:

```
rm -rf bin
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm i
tsc
```

Running `pulumi preview` again I get the same error as before:

```
Diagnostics:
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (pulumi-alpha-dev):
    error: Running program '/Users/brian/git/github/pulumi-alpha' failed with an unhandled exception:
    /Users/brian/git/github/pulumi-alpha/node_modules/pulumi-beta/index.ts:1
    import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Can anyone help guide me on how I can get this basic example to work?

Answer (score 0):

My question is basically a duplicate of this one: [How to have npm install a typescript dependency from a GitHub url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078974/how-to-have-npm-install-a-typescript-dependency-from-a-github-url). There are some good suggestions in that answer. One option that I used was to commit the `bin` directory to GitHub.