# Cannot import a TypeScript library that was installed from a GitHub fork

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I'm trying to use the [`probot`](https://github.com/probot/probot) library to build a GitHub app. However, as per [this issue](https://github.com/probot/probot/issues/1684), `probot` does not support ESM modules, and I need ESM modules in order to have my app function properly.

Fortunately, [this fork](https://github.com/pixelass/probot) adds ESM support to the library. However, after installing the library by running the following line:

```
npm i github:pixelass/probot#feat/esm-it-plz
```

which installs without issue, I'm unable to import the library. When I add the line:

```js
import { Probot } from "probot"
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'probot' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I even [made my own fork](https://github.com/Vagif12/probot/tree/esm) of the fork and, as suggested by [How to have npm install a typescript dependency from a GitHub url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078974/how-to-have-npm-install-a-typescript-dependency-from-a-github-url), added the following to the module's `package.json`:

```js
"postinstall": "tsc --outDir ./lib"
```

But even when I install my own fork, I get a different error:

```
Module '"probot"' has no exported member 'Probot'.ts(2305)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you check in the node_modules, what is actually being exported from probot?

Comment: Great catch @ApoorvaChikara. When I go the the definition located at `node_modules/probot/lib/index.d.ts` I have an empty export: `export {};`. Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara now this is interesting .. i made an experiment in which I installed the original probot, uninstalled it, and then tried re-installing my version. Interestingly, I get the below error:


```
npm ERR! path /Users/vagif/Desktop/github-ai-app/node_modules/probot
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c tsc --outDir ./lib
npm ERR! error TS5055: Cannot write file '/Users/vagif/Desktop/github-ai-app/node_modules/probot/lib/index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.```

Comment: Can you check the permission for this file? It seems it can't be written to this file. Maybe you can try to create an export member in your fork. There could be more issues like the command you are running might be on an incorrect path or script o/p is not going to correct lib path.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara permissions seem ok. For the previous message I sent, I actually got it working again on the installation of my own fork by deleting node_modules. I actually believe that the issue is with the line I added for "postinstall" , however I'm not sure what I should change it to. Any ideas?

Comment: What I can suggest here is, you can work on your own fork until you get an official release for probot with ESM support. As you mentioned, you were able to manage to run it, try to keep the same version, publish your own package and keep using it or if you don't want to publish keep it as a custom module in your code if you can manage it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break the issue into two.

- Consuming `probot` in your ts esm project
- Adding types to `probot`.

To allow you to consume `probot` immediately just add `someName.d.ts` file, with the following content:

```
declare module 'probot';
```

Now let's consider properly typing `probot`. The above will type probot as any. Forking the esm package to add types is possible, but in general I don't think it's the best approach. JS package update, but since you'll use a fork of a fork, you will get stuck on a certain version. If you do decide to more properly type `probot` I'd recommend to do it in the d.ts file as such:

```
declare module 'probot' {
    export type SomeExport = string;
}
```

This way you'll have proper typing, but still get any update to `probot`.